# How Can I populate a field.selection based on user choice in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I need help to populate field.selection values on run time Let me explain: I have a field.selection called Programs. When a user select a program I have another field.selection called projects.I want to populate projects under that specific program on to projects selection field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with OpenERP v7, that's not possible, as an alternative you have to either use many2one field. With new upcoming v8, this feature will be available.

Cheers,
Parthiv